# handling file of Spanish Dictionary

Tags: objective-c, string, file, file-io

I'm trying to get the contents of a file that has over 47,000 words(a dictionary).
My goal is to generate a random number and locate the word at the specific line of the file to get a different word mostly every time I run the program, then output that word.
I have been researching but I have not found any answer, this is what I have so far, it only takes characters, but I want words

```
//
//  main.m
//  wordaday
//
//  Created by Eddy Guzman on 11/5/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Eddy Guzman. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

bool checkFile( NSString * path)
{
    NSFileManager *filemgr;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: path ] == YES)
    {
        return TRUE;
        NSLog (@"File exists");
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog (@"File not found");
        return false;
    }

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        NSString * path = @"/Users/eddy30/Eddy's Documents/School/Millersville/Fall2013/wordaday/dictionary.txt";



        if(checkFile(path) == TRUE)
        {
            NSLog(@"WOHOOOO");
        }

        NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path];

        //NSFileHandle *myFile = fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path;
        int rand = arc4random_uniform(47049);
        char Word = [content characterAtIndex:rand];


        NSLog(@"Word of the day is: %c", Word);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will help if you learn that c and Objective-C are not anything like the same language. Using the proper tag for the one you're using will get you answers much more quickly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Between this step:

```
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

And this step:

```
char Word = [content characterAtIndex:rand];
NSLog(@"Word of the day is: %c", Word);
```

Hmm.  This is quite confusing.  As is, you're reading the entire file into an `NSString` called `content`, then picking a random character out of that `NSString`, and outputting it, claiming it to be a word.

How you actually fix this program will depend greatly on the format of the file you're reading.  You need a step to turn `content` into an `NSArray` of `NSStrings`, with each index of the array representing a different word in the dictionary.  If, for example, your file contents each word on a line by itself, you'll want to use this nice method:

```
NSArray *arrayOfWords = [content componentsSeperatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Then you'll use your randomly generated `int` as an index into this array, and then log it like this:

```
NSLog(@"Word of the day is: %@", [arrayOfWords objectAtIndex:rand]);
```

Without more detail in the original question, there's not much more I can help with.  I don't know the format of the original file.  I don't know if the original file, which you claim to be a dictionary, contains definitions, etc.  But this answer explains the gist of what you want to do.

---

EDIT: As a note, when generating your random number, you'll want to do this:

```
int rand = arc4random_uniform([arrayOfWords count]-1);
```

in order to avoid out of bounds indexes.